# htaccess when file not found, make first part php variable but retain all the rest

Tags: .htaccess

This is currently my htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]+)$ /negocio/?id=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.lujanventas.com/404.php
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

When the first directly is not found it passes it as a variable. But loses the rest of the URL. I want to retain all the rest of the URL except the first part, so that:

```
http://www.lujanventas.com/something/info/?var=1
```

Becomes:

```
http://www.lujanventas.com/negocio/info/?id=something&var=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the `[QSA]` flag (querystring append) to preserve the existing query string.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]+)$ /negocio/?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Update:

If you have multi-directory patterns to match like `something/info`, you'll need `/` following the matched character class, and remove the `$`.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio$2?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I forgot to add the directory to the example. Changing negocio.php to /negocio/ still gives me a 404 error. However it might be for the mistake in the example. Could you check it again?

Comment: Now both `lujanventas.com/something/?var=1` and `lujanventas.com/something/info/?var=1` are redirecting to: `lujanventas.com/negocio` (second should be directing to `lujanventas.com/negocio/info/`). It's however getting the variables correctly. I'm sure it's a simple change but It's above me

Comment: @Liso22 See changes above. `(/.+)?` added and appended as `$2 after `negocio`

Comment: It's working in the sense that it's retaining the path and variables but when going to: `lujanventas.com/something/info/` the address bar shows: `lujanventas.com/negocio/info/?id=something`. It's redirecting or something. I'm going to read about htaccess to see if I can update the answer

Comment: @Liso22 Without `[R]` at the end (with `[L,QSA]`) you should not be seeing the browser redirect.

Comment: Sorry I checked it thinking it was done but it's still not hiding the URL. I'm testing it here: `http://lujanventas.com/test/asdf` I'm going to check this as done and post it as it's technically answering my question. However if you find out what's the problem let me know